# Problems Reversing a Doubly Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have to reverse a doubly linked list(DLL) between two nodes. I've done this with singly linked lists(SLL), but I find it harder to do with DLL's? It might be the having to do it between two particular nodes.
Here is the code for my DLLNode & DLL. When I test this code it seems to do nothing to my DLL. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong??

EDIT: So I'm inputting a linked list 'a','b','c','d','e','f' and call twist('b','e'): This should result in the linked list 'a' 'b' 'e' 'd' 'c' 'f'

```
class DoublyLinkedListNode:
def __init__(self, item, prevnode = None, nextnode = None):
    self._data = item
    self.setnext(nextnode)
    self.setprev(prevnode)

def data(self):
    return self._data

def next(self):
    return self._next

def prev(self):
    return self._prev

def setprev(self, prevnode):
    self._prev = prevnode

def setnext(self, nextnode):
    self._next = nextnode

class DoublyLinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self._head = None
    self._tail = None
    self._length = 0

def _newnode(self, item, nextnode = None, prevnode = None):
    return DoublyLinkedListNode(item, nextnode, prevnode)

def addfirst(self, item):
    if self.isempty():
        return self._addtoempty(item)
    node = self._newnode(item, None, self._head)
    self._head.setprev(node)
    self._head = node
    self._length += 1

def addlast(self, item):
    if self.isempty():
        return self._addtoempty(item)
    node = self._newnode(item, self._tail, None)
    self._tail.setnext(node)
    self._tail = node
    self._length += 1

def _addtoempty(self, item):
    node = self._newnode(item, None, None)
    self._head = self._tail = node
    self._length = 1

def removefirst(self):
    if len(self) <= 1:
        return self._removelastitem()
    data = self._head.data()
    self._head = self._head.next()
    self._head.setprev(None)
    self._length -= 1
    return data

def removelast(self):
    if len(self) <= 1:
        return self._removelastitem()
    data = self._tail.data()
    self._tail = self._tail.prev()
    self._tail.setnext(None)
    self._length -= 1
    return data

def _removelastitem(self):
    if self.isempty():
        return None # Should probably raise an error.
    data = self._head.data()
    self._head = self._tail = None
    self._length = 0
    return data

def twist(self, endpt1, endpt2):
    current = self._head
    while current != None:
        if current.data() == endpt1:
            current.next().setnext(endpt2.next())
            endpt2.setnext(current.next())
            current.setnext(endpt2)
        else:
            current = current.next()

def isempty(self):
    return len(self) == 0

def _nodes(self):
    node = self._head
    while node is not None:
        yield node
        node = node.next()

def __iter__(self):
    for node in self._nodes():
        yield node.data()

def __len__(self):
    return self._length

def __str__(self):
    items = [str(data) for data in self]
    return ", ".join(items)
```

Here is the test I'm running:

```
    def testtwist1(self):
        n = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
        L = DoublyLinkedList()
        for i in n:
            L.addlast(i)
        L.twist(2,5)
        print(L)   # returns the list 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri But slice notatation, or even a `__getitem__` method, has not been implemented.

Comment: Please edit the original question and add these details.

Comment: Your current code for `twist` doesn't make any sense. You refer to `first` and `current` variables which don't exist, which makes it very hard to tell what you were intending the code to do. It's also unclear if `twist` is supposed to take `DoublyLinkedListNode` instances as its arguments or if it will be given `data` values instead.

Comment: @Blckknght I am such a spaz, I have twenty different versions of this function (I'm new to Python and so my coding is messy at times)--I fixed it to represent what I'm running!

Comment: Please provide the rest of the test driver code.  What you've posted has no main program, so it cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Now you've deleted the **twist** method.  Also, please fix your indentation (all the **def**s have to be indented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this executes at all.  You've apparently set up a DLL, and then called **DLL.twist('b', 'e')**.  Thus, endpt1 = 'b' and endpt2 = 'e'.  You then compare endpt1 to current.data, but then you access endpt2.next.  *endpt2 is a single-character string*.

You never reference the **prev** pointers at all.

The only time you try to alter anything is when you hit node **b**.  Then you seem to try to exchange the **next** pointers of **b** and **e** (so **b.next** is **f**, and **e.next** is **c**, but that's all.

At this point, I expect that your forward links give you two lists: a->b->f and c->d->e->c (a cycle), and that the backward links are unchanged.

Get pencil and paper or a white board and walk through these changes, one statement at a time; that's what I do ...

---

I recovered **twist** from your previous post, fixed the indentation, and ran.  As I explain above, this faults in execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 113, in <module>
    L.twist(2,5)
  File "so.py", line 102, in twist
    current.next().setnext(endpt2.next())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
```

There is no such thing as **2.next()**.  I don't think you're actually getting to your **print** statement.  Also, **print(L)** will not print the node values in order; you haven't included a **__repr__** method for your DLL object.  **__str__** would do the job, but you've use the list head pointer as if it were an iterable over the forward-linked list.

I strongly recommend that you back up and approach this with incremental programming: write a method or a few lines, test that, and don't continue until that works as you expect.  Yes, this means that you're writing detailed tests as you go ... that's a good thing.  Keep them, and keep running them.